# eager load singleton object in spring boot without annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a utility class which I want to instantiate at the time of loading spring boot application. Is there any possible place where I can call getInstance method of the class to create the object?

Point to note is that I can not annotate this class with any spring annotation because this class will be called directly and not injected in a spring component. Reason for this is that it will be used a bit lower in hierrarchy compared to component and I don't want to pass it from component to where it needs to be used. Also, the code where this singleton object needs to be used can also not be annotated as its a legacy code and will involve lot of changes.

Comment: "this class will be called directly and not injected in a spring component" - how are you planing to instantiate this class at the place where it is called? Its always good to provide a minimum viable example so that we can understand your problem better. There might be that you are violating a design principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should decide whether you would like to maintain this utility class in spring (so that it will be responsible for its lifecycle, will be able to inject the instance of this class into beans and so force).

If you want to make this class "unknown" to spring at all, you can create an event listener in spring that will be called by spring when the application context is started. This can be done in any `@Configuration` class including the main class (annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` which is also a configuration under the hood):

```
@EventListener
public void onApplicationStarted(ApplicatationReadyEvent evt) {
    UtilClass.INSTANCE(); // instantiate whatever
}
```

Another option is to just place the line `UtilClass.INSTANCE()` in method main before you trigger the spring boot loading. In this case it will load even before the spring starts at all.

Now if you do want to manage it with spring, this means that you have somewhere bean like:

```
@Component
public class MySampleBean {
   @Autowired // better constructor injection, but not relevant for this question
   private UtilClass utilClass;

   public void foo() {
      ... 
      utilClass.doSomething();
      ...
   }
}
```

In this case, assuming you *don't want to put any spring annotations on the `UtilClass`*, you can do the following:

```
 @Configuration
 public class MySpringConfiguration {

      @Bean
      public UtilClass utilClass() {
          return UtilClass.INSTANCE();
      }
 }
```

Here is what happens in this case:

Spring creates a bean of type `UtilClass` by calling this method. But this method as a regular java code returns the same singleton instance. So Spring will "Know" this bean (it will be stored in Application Context, however it will be the same instance as a singleton and you'll be able to reuse it from outside the "spring" part of the application.